# How to keep function param reference on re-renders - React

Tags: reactjs

My custom hook:

```
const useFetch = <R, B>(
  url: string,
  method: Methods,
  body: B | undefined = undefined,
  headers: { [key: string]: string } = {}
) => {
  const [response, setResponse] = useState<R | null>(null);
  const [error, setError] = useState<string | null>(null);

  const user = useSelector((state: RootState) => state.user);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      dispatch(onRequest(true));
      try {
        if (user.jwt) {
          headers['Authorization'] = `Bearer ${user.jwt}`;
        }
        const result = await api<R, B>(url, method, body, headers);
        setResponse(result as R);
      } catch (error) {
        setError(error);
        dispatch(onFailure(false, error));
      } finally {
        dispatch(onFinish(false));
      }
    })();
  }, [body, dispatch, method, url, user.jwt]); // headers should be included here, but i've removed it because of loops.

  return {
    response,
    error
  };
};
```

if i include in `useEffect` deps a `headers` param, then i would get infinite loop, because of `{} === {}` - `false`. How to keep reference to a `headers` param, so i won't get infinite loops?

Comment: I think you have to cache the headers yourself and make a deep comparison. You could use lodash isEqual for that.

Comment: You should have the default headers value created before the useFetch declaration so its default value will always be the same object and therefore useEffect will not enter an infinite loop because of that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was thinking about `useMemo`, `useCallback`, but they're overkill for my case, so i've tried `useRef` to keep a reference to the headers:

```
const { current: hdrs } = useRef(headers); // destructuring current, so we won't have to use refConst.current

if (user.jwt) {
  hdrs['Authorization'] = `Bearer ${user.jwt}`;
}

const result = await api<R, B>(url, method, body, hdrs);
```

Then we can include `hdrs` inside `useEffect` deps array.